# How to use ajax in razor to not reload a popup

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, popup

I'm using a form in popup with razor which has to send data to controller and receive back the response from the controller. Actually I'm working with a simple form but the problem is when I submit the data by clicking on button the popup disappear and I have to reopen the pop to get the data sent by the controller . So I want to use Ajax in order to not reload the popup 
The code of Ajax could be something like this but this one doesn't work

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "popupConvertTxt" }))
```

The code of the actual form is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
     {
        <img width="60" height="60" alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAY............" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imageFile" value="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAY.........."/>
        @Html.TextArea("resultText")
        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" id="l" value="Envoyer"/>
    }
```

Comment: have you included required js libraries?

Comment: yes If you're talking about this one : @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to include following js libraries**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**View example**

```
<div id="result"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    @Html.TextArea("resultText")
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would mention that the form code is included in the div that contain the popup that I want to get. So please how could I render it ?

Comment: the popup that I want to render is not in a partial view

Comment: you are just trying to avoid full post back on popup's button click, right?
        whereever your popup contents are, just put those inside Ajax.BeginForm().